# Pass UrlName file path in command line while running SH file

Tags: python, git, shell, sh, webpagetest

I'm implementing https://github.com/siedi/webpagetest-influxdb .While running the run-tests.sh shell script which takes URL(of a web page) as a a parameter and i want to pass a text file which takes login information.

As mentioned in - https://sites.google.com/a/webpagetest.org/docs/advanced-features/webpagetest-batch-processing-command-line-tool ,i tried to write my URL to an external file and used  --urlfile=/foo/urls.txt (like sh run-tests.sh --urlfile=/foo/urls.txt) which is in Python.

Above method in SH is not seem to be working

Can anyone help me on how can i pass these two files along with sh command if its possible.

Comment: which is it? `shell` or `batch-file`?

Comment: I have removed your [tag:batch-file] tag and replaced it with the [tag:python] tag. Please be careful not to use incorrect or ill advised tags when choosing the potential audience for your question.

Comment: Aplogies  !!and thanks for correcting it